# Java inform a thread from another thread between different classes

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency

Below method runs on main thread in 'Controller' class. It sends request packet to server to get device list.

```
public List<Device> getDeviceList(){
   networkServer.sendMsg(deviceListReqPacket);
   //wait till response returns. ???
}
```

This method runs on another thread in 'Server' class which reads data from server.

```
private void readDeviceList() {
    // read packet from socket 
    List<nwkDeviceInfo_t> listdevice = networkServerDriver.getDeviceLists(packet);

    }
}
```

What can i do to make getDeviceList() method wait until, readDeviceList() method construct listDevice.And get the listDevice object? Im a little bit confused. Am i trying something not possible or am i doing in a completely wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If your instances (of the above classes) run on the same JVM but in different threads, use one of the [blocking queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) that come with Java.
If they communicate over a network (e.g. HTTP and such) seems like the read would block until the write is done (and indeed received on the other side). So in that case, you already have the behaviour you want.